# Nodejs mysql.createConnection not accepting password

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker

I am having trouble connecting to a MySQL database in a Docker container using NodeJs.

The error states: `"Error: Access denied for user 'username'@'172.19.0.3' (using password: NO)"`, but as far as I can see, I am giving a password.

*So my question is: why does the error state that I am not using a password, while I clearly gave a password?*

Part of my code:

```
  /* file: ./nodejs-server/database/database.js */ 
  const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

  let db = await mysql
    .createConnection({ // Error: Access denied for user 'username'@'172.19.0.3' (using password: NO)
      host: env.DB_HOST,
      port: 3306,
      user: env.MYSQL_USER,
      password: env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
      database: env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
      authSwitchHandler: (_, cb) => {
        // workaround for node mysql bug #1507
        cb(null, Buffer.alloc(0));
      },
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      throw new Error('Could not connect to the database');
    });
```

I checked the value for `env.MYSQL_PASSWORD` and it contains the correct password.
I an not sure whether this error is caused by wrong syntax, or by the setup of my Docker containers.

```
# file: ./mysql-server/Dockerfile
FROM mysql:latest
VOLUME ["/etc/mysql", "/var/lib/mysql"]
EXPOSE 3306
```

```
# file: ./nodejs-server/Dockerfile
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "run", "watch" ]
```

```
# file: ./docker-composer.yml
version: "3.3"
services:
  nodejs:
    build: ./nodejs-server
    ports:
      - "8001:8080"
    links:
      - db:db
    env_file:
      - ./.env-example
    volumes:
      - ./nodejs-server:/usr/src/app
  db:
    build: ./mysql-server
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-server/data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d #A folder /mysql-server/data with a .sql file needs to exist
    env_file:
      - ./.env-example
```

The nodejs and mysql containers are running, as I can login to the commandline and nodejs is correctly sowing a "Hello world" page.
Also, the Docker containers are connecting, because when I stop the mysql container, I get another error telling me that no connection could be made.

I have `` GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `username`@`%` `` and `` GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `databasename`.* TO `username`@`%` `` so the permissions seem to be ok.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to allow user to connect from 172.19.* as docker container IP could be unpredictable and MySql user permission has to be properly set.

Comment: I have ```GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `username`@`%` ``` and ```GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `databasename`.* TO `username`@`%` ```, so I would expect it to work. Also, why does the error message state: ```"using password: NO"```?